# Cant get java stream to work with arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

So, I have been playing around with java streams a bit, and found something very frustrating.

I want to make a list of this type of object (Customer), and after that use a stream to filter out all those objects where glad == false.

```
package com.company;

public class Customer {

    public String name;
    public int points;
    public boolean glad;

    public Customer(String name, int points, boolean glad) {
        this.name = name;
        this.points = points;
        this.glad = glad;
    }

    public boolean isGlad() {
        return this.glad;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try doing it with a regular array, everything seems to work just fine:

```
Customer kunde1 = new Customer("jens", 20, true);
Customer kunde2 = new Customer("marie", 20, false);
Customer kunde3 = new Customer("niels", 20, false);
Customer kunde4 = new Customer("jens", 20, true);
Customer kunde5 = new Customer("jens", 20, true);

Customer[] kunderne = {kunde1,kunde2,kunde3,kunde4,kunde5};

Customer[] filtered = Stream.of(kunderne)
    .filter(Customer::isGlad)
    .toArray(Customer[]::new);
```

But whenever I try to create the stream from something other than an array, like an ArrayList, I am not able to access the object attributes within my lambda statement

```
ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

Customer kunde1 = new Customer("jens", 20, true);
Customer kunde2 = new Customer("marie", 20, false);
Customer kunde3 = new Customer("niels", 20, false);
Customer kunde4 = new Customer("jens", 20, true);
Customer kunde5 = new Customer("jens", 20, true);

customers.add(kunde1);
customers.add(kunde2);
customers.add(kunde3);
customers.add(kunde4);
customers.add(kunde5);


Customer[] filtered = Stream.of(kunderne)
    .filter(Customer::isGlad)
    .toArray(Customer[]::new);
```

But this code won't even run. Why does this happen, and why does it only seem to work with arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you wanted to do.

```java
      Customer[] filtered = Stream.of(kunderne).filter(Customer::isGlad).map(
            cust -> new Customer(cust.name, cust.points, cust.glad)).toArray(
                  Customer[]::new);

      for (Customer c : filtered) {
         System.out.println(c.name + " " + c.points + " " + c.glad);
      }
```

You needed to map the filtered customer to a new customer and then put those in an array.  Another option would be to add a constructor that takes an existing customer and uses that as input.  Here is how that would work.

```java
      Customer[] filtered = Stream.of(kunderne).filter(Customer::isGlad).map(
            Customer::new).toArray(Customer[]::new);

      for (Customer c : filtered) {
         System.out.println(c.name + " " + c.points + " " + c.glad);
      }

     // modified customer class with additional constructor

    class Customer {
       public String  name;
       public int     points;
       public boolean glad;

       public Customer(String name, int points, boolean glad) {
          this.name = name;
          this.points = points;
          this.glad = glad;
       }

       public Customer(Customer cust) {
          this(cust.name, cust.points, cust.glad);
       }

       public boolean isGlad() {
          return this.glad;
       }
    }
```

Comment: nice! thanks! but does this solve the problem of not being able to acces the attributes?

Comment: The second method should, if you have access to the class you can add the constructor.  But someone, somehow, must be able to access the attributes.  Otherwise, the class wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: You can always use `Arrays.stream(kunderne)` to create a stream.

Comment: One final suggestion.  Clearly you have access to `isGlad` which returns the boolean.  If you add `getters` to the class and make the fields `private` you could use the first stream method I showed and have read-only access to the class fields.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a method as `Stream.of(List<T>)`.
You should use `cusomters.stream()` which will convert your list into the stream.

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because `Stream.of(cusomters)` is creating the one element Stream with the `ArrayList` object inside - obviously there is not method

```
public static boolean isGlad(ArrayList<Customer> customers) {
    return false;
}
```

and this is why the code is not running

When you are passing `Customer[]` object to the `Stream.of` instead of `of` method version

```
 public static<T> Stream<T> of(T t)
```

overloaded

```
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T... values)
```

is being used and everything is fine

Comment: Oh okay, so i should not use the stream.of?

Comment: @AskSejsbo when the source is a collection, like an `ArrayList`, just call `stream()` on it.